# Change the same vector in several mutable lambdas

Tags: c++, qt, vector, lambda

I have two different Qt buttons of type `QPushButton*` and a `vector<QString>`. Each button has to show a message box which says what the value of the last element of the vector is and if the user presses Yes insert a specific value into the vector. The code below shows how I do this (the `QMessageBox::information` are only there for debugging reasons). Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
std::vector<QString> myVector;
myVector.push_back("First value");
QObject::connect(button1,&QPushButton::clicked,myWidget,[myVector=move(myVector)]() mutable{
    QMessageBox::information(NULL,"",std::to_string(myVector.size()).c_str());
    if(QMessageBox::question(NULL,"","The value of the last element in the vector is " + myVector[myVector.size() - 1] + ".\nDo you want to insert a new value?",QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes){
        myVector.push_back("Value inserted by button 1");
    }
});
QObject::connect(button2,&QPushButton::clicked,myWidget,[myVector=move(myVector)]() mutable{
    QMessageBox::information(NULL,"",std::to_string(myVector.size()).c_str());
    if(QMessageBox::question(NULL,"","The value of the last element in the vector is " + myVector[myVector.size() - 1] + ".\nDo you want to insert a new value?",QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes){
        myVector.push_back("Value inserted by button 2");
    }
});
```

I'm sure that the vector is empty at no time.

When I press Button 1, everything works as it should. But when I press Button 2, the message box shows that the size of the vector is 0 and I know for sure that that's not true. When I swap the two `QObject::connect` functions, that is put the one for Button 2 before the one for Button 1, the behaviour of the buttons swaps: Button 2 works normally and Button 1 thinks that the vector is empty.

It doesn't seem that this is the correct way of making two lambdas capture the same vector as mutable. Why is that? What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You've moved from the same variable twice.  Think about what that does.

Comment: @NathanOliver OK, but what's the correct way of doing then? Is it enough to only use move in one of the lambdas and not in the other?

Comment: Why not store a reference to the vector in each lambda if they are supposed to share it?

Comment: @NathanOliver You mean `[&myVector]` instead of `[myVector=move(myVector)]` in both lambdas? I've tried that and it causes the program to crash.

Comment: I really need to see a MCVE to tell why but I will guess that this is done in a scope that you leave but the lambdas live on.  If that is the case you can make a shared pointer for the vector like `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<QString>>` and then copy the shared pointer into each lambda.  Now the vector will be shared between them and will live until both lambdas go out of scope.  I can write this up as an answer if this is the case.

Comment: @DonaldDuck , You moved the vector to the first lambda. since `std::vector` supports move semantics, you have to expect that the vector will become empty outside the first lambda (after the first `connect` call).

Comment: @NathanOliver If I understand correctly what you mean, that is the case. Both the vectors and the lambdas are declared in a function which only opens the current window and is left as soon as the window is opened. So you can post an answer which explains in detail how you suggest doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code you are moving from the vector twice.  Doing that cause the second lambda to get a vector that is in a valid but unspecifed state.  What you need to do is share the vector between the two lambdas.  Since you are doing this in a function whose scope you are leaving it is not enough just to take a reference to the vector as the vector will go out of scope and the lambda will have dangling references.

What you can do is create a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<QString>>` and capture that `shared_ptr` by value in each of the lambdas.  This makes sure the vector will have the appropriate life time and that both buttons operate on the same vector.  Your could would look something like

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<QString>> myVector;
myVector->push_back("First value");
QObject::connect(button1,&QPushButton::clicked,myWidget,[=]() mutable{
    QMessageBox::information(NULL,"",std::to_string(myVector->size()).c_str());
    if(QMessageBox::question(NULL,"","The value of the last element in the vector is " + (*myVector)[myVector.size() - 1] + ".\nDo you want to insert a new value?",QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes){
        myVector->push_back("Value inserted by button 1");
    }
});
QObject::connect(button2,&QPushButton::clicked,myWidget,[=]() mutable{
    QMessageBox::information(NULL,"",std::to_string(myVector.size()).c_str());
    if(QMessageBox::question(NULL,"","The value of the last element in the vector is " + (*myVector)[myVector->size() - 1] + ".\nDo you want to insert a new value?",QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes){
        myVector->push_back("Value inserted by button 2");
    }
});
```

Also note that I changed `[myVector->size()]` to `[myVector->size() - 1]` as `vector[size()]` is one past then end of the vector which you cannot access.

Comment: Do I need any `#include` to be able to use `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Yes.  `#include <memory>` is what you will need.  Qt probably has their own version if you want to stick with Qt types.  I just used the `std` one as it is, well, standard :-)

Comment: If I want to use another variable in the lambda without changing it, for example if the other variable is `int myVar`, should I do `[myVar,=]`?

Comment: @DonaldDuck If you use [=] it will capture everything by value that you use in the lambda body.  If you want other options see the Lambda capture section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)